# Did the Crusaders try to justify the First Crusade as a defensive war?

Tags: war, crusades

Did any Crusaders participating in the [First Crusade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Crusade) characterize it as a defensive, rather than aggressive, campaign? If so, what were their arguments for characterizing it this way? How do modern historians evaluate those arguments?

Comment: There is a request to make the requested answer more fact based than opinion based. Can you please modify your question?

Comment: @AstorFlorida And what wording would you suggest?

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable. There is no "the" truth. There are as many truths as there are people to perceive them.

Comment: I've tried to change it into a question we can actually answer. If you're not happy with it, you can obviously change it back.

Comment: Although note the question got closed before i could do it. So it will likely remain closed unless concerns are addressed.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786) The term [defensive war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_war) appears to date to the 19th century, so I think it is unlikely.

Comment: In the times of crusades the attitude to war was different from nowadays: people did not need to justify it by defense or fighting for democracy - liberating Jerusalem and the Holy Sepulture from infidels was good enough. Note that all but defensive wars were outlawed only in the XX-th century by the League of Nations  and the UN  (and I am not even sure about the former.)

Comment: Note that at the time of Muhammad's death, all of the following lands were Christian: Iberia; all the coastal regions of Morocco, Algeria, Tunisia, and Libya; Egypt; Greater Syria; Turkey; Iraq; and Iran. Exactly when are you specifying as the "end of Arab and Islamic conquest" so that you can claim subsequent loss of previously Christian land as "unwarranted Christian aggression"?  And how are you justifying that choice?

Comment: @NeMo Despite your surgical efforts, this is still not a great question. At least the original had some thought processes, but there are no sources, no citations, the briefest of historical allusion. It's also an enormous question. Many volumes have been written on the topic (and the same thing for other nations, like Rome's expansion), but where that evidence goes is still fairly subjective.

Comment: I thought it was best to remove subjective elements which were likely to generate debates, not answers. If you think it can be improved further, that would be helpful.

Comment: "The Crusades" were composed of several completely different events. The WP page contains **63** links to individual "crusades", carried out over a period of half a millennium. IMHO this could probably be answered at least quasi-objectively if it could be narrowed to **ONE** particular Crusade.

Comment: I've chosen the first crusade. The conquest of Jerusalem is what most people would think of concerning the subject

Comment: I've refined the question a little bit. IMO it is now answerable without relying on opinion; *however* it could still be improved with preliminary research.

Comment: @MCW "*The term defensive war appears to date to the 19th century, so I think it is unlikely.*" Fair enough, but "just war" was known at least since St. Augustine

Comment: I'd update the question to cite Augustine's definition of "just war" and remove "defensive war" The anachronism is a (for me) a real obstacle.  I get squirrely about questions will undefined terms. they tend to result in endless discussion, lots of rancour and extra work for moderators.

Comment: @mcw in that case would it be a duplicate of https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/25733/to-what-extent-were-st-augustines-just-war-principles-used-in-the-first-crusad?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The terms "defensive", "aggressive" that you use in this question are modern. They cannot be applied to those events.
Official propaganda styled the crusades as the reaction on the Arab conquest of Jerusalem which happened almost 4 centuries before the start of the crusades. They called these wars "liberation of the  Holy Sepulcher from the infidel".

Comment: The terms might be modern, but they are retroactively applicable. They'd plenty of scholarship and debate around eg whether Rome's expansion was defensive or was rooted in their ambitions.